# Cut 2 strings in random place until end of string and recombine parts C++

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to take 2 string both cut in a random place and copy both until the until the end. 
Then take them and copy from start to place I cut at.
Then recombine first string start to cut with second string cut to ending and then vise-versa with other two parts.

So far I have:

```
 std::random_device seeder;
 std::mt19937 engine(seeder());  
 std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 8175);

 int p = dist(engine); //some random number from 1 to 8175
 string cutstringA1 = returnvarA.substr(p,(8176-p));

    string cutstringA1 = returnvarA.substr(p,(8176-p)); //cut place to end;
    string cutstringB1 = returnvarB.substr(p,(8176-p));

    string cutstringA2 = returnvarA.substr(1,(p-1)); //start to cut place
    string cutstringB2 = returnvarB.substr(1,(p-1));

    string reconstructA = cutstringA1+cutstringB2; //recombine
    string reconstructB=cutstringB1+cutstringA2;
```

For some reason I always get "terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string"

I checked returnvarA length with size() and confirmed length to be 8176.

Can anyone see an error?

Comment: Now I understand how I would have learned a lot even from coding simple hello-world-like programs if I had started with C++ instead of Basic and C#.

Comment: Just a quick note, if you want to use string::substr to start from a position and go all the way to the end, use std::string::npos - it's the largest possible unsigned int, and if the second argument in substr is longer than the string, it stops at the end of the string. Trying to manually do the math for how much string is left is unnecessary

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is thrown by one of those substr calls? Did you also check the length of the other input string?

Comment: @SeanM Are you *sure* sure? [This](http://ideone.com/amKkzk) code runs successfully on GCC and VS2015 RC. How does that stripped-down example run on your setup?

Comment: Post a **complete** but minimal example that exhibits the problem.